# How to find panda3d source directory?

Tags: python, bash, macos

I'm trying to install panda3d but I keep running into errors. It says "After placing the thirdparty directory inside the panda3d source directory,
you may build Panda3D using a command like the following:

`bash
python makepanda/makepanda.py --everything --installer`
" 
When I run that on terminal I get the error `python: can't open file 'makepanda/makepandacore.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I'm not sure what the "source directory" is so that may be the problem. I just put the downloaded file into the panda3d folder.

Comment: Building on Rod's answer... I wasn't able to do the instruction "Extract the contents of downloaded file to thirdparty folder inside of src folder" so I just located where the thirdparty folder and put in my unzipped downloaded file. The "Run the build command" took awhile to load, more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this process as outlined on their [github repo](https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d) for MacOS and it worked with no problems:

1.Download precompiled third party packages for MacOS:

`wget https://www.panda3d.org/download/panda3d-1.9.4/panda3d-1.9.4-tools-mac.tar.gz`

2.Clone panda3d's github repo:

`git clone https://github.com/panda3d/panda3d.git`

3.Navigate to repo root directory:

`cd panda3d`

4.Make a `thirdparty` directory under `panda/src`:

`mkdir panda/src/thirdparty`

Extract the contents of downloaded file to `thirdparty` folder inside of `src` folder:

`tar -xvzf ../panda3d-1.9.4-tools-mac.tar.gz -C panda/src/thirdparty`

5.Run the build command:

`python makepanda/makepanda.py --everything --installer`

5.Install the generated `.dmg` file through finder as most MacOS apps.

Comment: I tested on MacOS and edited my answer accordingly, good luck ;)

Comment: I will try this once I figure out my terminal. It seems to be pretty messed up as I constantly run into errors. Thanks!